# How to implement jwt authentication using django rest auth?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am trying to implement jwt authentication for my project. I used django-rest-auth for authentication.
The [official rest-auth docs says](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html?highlight=jwt#jwt-support-optional).

Add the following configuration value to your settings file to enable JWT authentication.

```
REST_USE_JWT = True
```

But its returning token with user info. not `acces` and `refresh` token.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 packages you should refer:

- [pyjwt](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: please add `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` instead of `django-rest-framework-jwt` as it Is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found the `django-rest-auth` project has not been developed for more than two years and it is recommended to use its fork [`dj-rest-auth`](https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth).

Using [`dj-rest-auth`](https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth) solved my problem.